# Context returning as undefined when exposing it through a custom hook with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

I'm working on a typescript version of [Kent Dodd's pattern](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) for using React Context with useReducer. You can see [my version of the app at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/argument-for-context-1u3nt?file=/src/context/AuthProvider.tsx).

In short, there are custom hooks that expose the contexts for state and dispatch. But when I try to use them, the contexts are returned as `undefined`.

I'm probably missing something really obvious in the difference between what he's doing and I'm doing, but I'm not seeing it. A fresh pair of eyes would be great. Thanks.

The Provider and the hooks looks like this

```
const AuthProvider = ({ children }: ProviderProps) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AuthStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <AuthDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </AuthDispatchContext.Provider>
    </AuthStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

function useAuthState() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthState needs a context");
  }
  return context;
}

function useAuthDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(AuthDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useAuthDispatch needs a context");
  }
  return context;
}
```

The use of the hooks looks like this.

```
export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useAuthDispatch();
  const { isAuthenticated, user } = useAuthState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("dispatch", dispatch);
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <div>Authenticated: {isAuthenticated ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      <div>user: {user ? user : "not logged in yet"}</div>

      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "logout" })}>Logout</button>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "login" })}>Login</button>
      )}
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you try wrapping `<AuthProvider><App /></AuthProvider>` like this instead of inside of `App.js`?

Comment: That did it. Thank you @AntonioErdeljac. I knew it a different pair of eyes would see it.

Comment: Can I write it as an answer for others to see as well?

Comment: Absolutely. Please do.